# BrowserRouter is not able to render the component

Tags: node.js, reactjs

I have created a route '/' which renders a Home component but the component is not getting rendered.

Below is the error

```
react-dom.development.js:18970 The above error occurred in the <BrowserRouter> component:

    at BrowserRouter (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:43555:5)
    at div
    at App

Consider adding an error boundary to your tree to customize error handling behavior.

Visit https://reactjs.org/link/error-boundaries to learn more about error boundaries.
```

Below is the **app.js** code

```
import React from 'react';
import './App.css';
import {Route, BrowserRouter , Routes} from 'react-router-dom';
import Home from './pages/Home';



function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <BrowserRouter>
      <Routes>
      <Route exact path="/" element ={<Home/>}/>
      </Routes>
      </BrowserRouter>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Below is the **Home.js** code

```
import React from 'react'

function Home() {
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Home Page</h1>
    </div>
  )
}

export default Home
```

Comment: Please update your question with the actual error, not a link to an image

Comment: What version of React are you working on?

Comment: @DreamBold 18.2.0

Comment: Did you add `react-router-dom` ? Your code is working correctly https://codesandbox.io/s/condescending-leavitt-2sviip?file=/src/App.js:73-89

Comment: @DreamBold I uninstalled the react-router-dom  and installed again and it started working thankyou

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the dependency modules' compatibility, you can remove the `node_modules` folder with `rm -rf ./node_modules` and run `npm i` or `yarn` to install the dependencies all again. Hope it helps!